# How to start up a server in jenkins to run acceptance tests in parallel?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

As part of the build, these are the stages I have:

1. Compile and package the project
2. Parallel Jobs:

   - Run unit tests
   - Start up server by executing the jar file created in stage 1
   - Wait for server to be ready and run acceptance tests
     against that

The question is when acceptance tests are finished, how do I signal the other parallel job to shutdown the server? At the moment the jar execution process remains running even if I kill the build from the Jenkins.

Also, in the event of the build being cancelled manually, how can we capture that event and signal the server to shut itself down using scripted pipeline/groovy?

Sample code:

```
node('jenkins-jenkins-slave') {

    stage('Parallel jobs') {
        parallel 
        stage('Preparing server for acceptance test') {
            script {

                def propertiesString = ''
                def jvmOptions = ''

                def properties = readProperties file: "${propertiesFile}".toString()
                properties.each { k, v ->
                    propertiesString = propertiesString + "-D${k}=${v} ".toString()
                }

                sh "java ${jvmOptions} -Dloader.path=${loaderPath} ${propertiesString}-jar ${jarFile} --spring.profiles.active=${activeProfiles}"
            }
        },
        stage('Acceptance tests') {
            script {
                def scriptName = 'wait_until_env_ready.sh'
                def exists = fileExists "$scriptName"
                if(!exists) {
                    def scriptContent = libraryResource "${scriptName}"
                    writeFile file: "${scriptName}", text: scriptContent
                    sh "chmod +x ${scriptName}"
                }
                sh "./wait_until_env_ready.sh http://localhost:8090/manage/health"
                sh "mvn -B test -Dmaven.repo.local=/root/.m2/repository -DskipTests=true -DskipITs=false"
                // How to signal the above stage to shut down the jar execution?
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up writing a shutdown controller in my app as suggested here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [`post`-`always` -section](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post).

Also you need some way to terminate the server. For example find its PID and `kill` it within the `post`.

Comment: So is that a best practice to kill the process or is there anything that Jenkins provides?

Comment: @xbmono I don't know about any mechanism in Jenkins.